# Python timedelta class minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, timedelta

How to get timedelta's minutes and seconds(ex: 2:01)? Is there any formula for this?

I've tried this, but it really didn't work well

```
minutes = int(diff.seconds/60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isayahs answer works great, but if you don't want to use any libraries you could do something similar to this:

```
minutes = seconds // 60
remainingSeconds = seconds % 60
print(str(minutes) + ":" + str(remainingSeconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question but if you are looking for a `timedelta` object where `seconds = 121` then:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta(minutes=2, seconds=1)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=121)
```